# Java Google Engine Library

Tags: nlp, information-retrieval, java

i want a java library, to search a text on Google and returns some pages based on text and semantic similarity. is there any API doing this job?
i wrote a crawler myself and search to specific depth from a root page, but i dont know how to input a text as a search query for Google.

Comment: Firstly, since you're writing your own crawler, I hope your crawler obeys robots.txt of the sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google provides the *Custom Search API* which you can use to search Google from code.

You'll need to create a google account if you don't already have one, create a custom search engine, generate an API key, and then use that as part of your request. You can get the results as JSON or as an Atom XML.

The documentation for this is available at https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview

There's no java library, as such, so to actually call the API, you'll need to either use `java.net.URL` and `java.net.URLConnection`, or a REST client library like the one that [jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) ships with.